# How can I update expected value with old value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have one object

```
objTime = {
    "scheduleStartDate": "2022-07-13T12:00:00.540+00:00",
    "slotDuration":30,
    "noOfSlots":5,
}
```

**I have to add scheduleEndDate dynamically by using slotDuraion key and noOfSlots is my loop length.**

```
for (let i = 0; i < objTime.noOfSlots; i++) {
          let startDateTime = moment(objTime.scheduleStartDate);
          let expectedEndDateTime = moment(startDateTime).add(objTime.slotDuration, "minutes");
          console.log(
            `Start : ${moment(startDateTime).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss")} | End : ${moment(expectedEndDateTime).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss")}`
          );
        }
```

But it not works as accept
I want o/p like this.

```
Start : 13-07-2022 05:30:00 | End : 13-07-2022 06:00:00
Start : 13-07-2022 06:00:00 | End : 13-07-2022 06:30:00
Start : 13-07-2022 06:30:00 | End : 13-07-2022 07:00:00
Start : 13-07-2022 07:00:00 | End : 13-07-2022 07:30:00
Start : 13-07-2022 07:30:00 | End : 13-07-2022 08:00:00
```

Any moment.js function for same I am using NodeJS.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a little tweak to your implementation to manipulate the date time using the `i` value

```js
const objTime = {
    "scheduleStartDate": "2022-07-13T12:00:00.540+00:00",
    "slotDuration": 30,
    "noOfSlots": 5,
}
for (let i = 0; i < objTime.noOfSlots; i++) {
    let startDateTime = moment(objTime.scheduleStartDate).add(objTime.slotDuration * (i), "minutes");
    let expectedEndDateTime = moment(objTime.scheduleStartDate).add(objTime.slotDuration * (i + 1), "minutes");
    console.log(`Start : ${moment(startDateTime).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss")} | End : ${moment(expectedEndDateTime).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss")}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```